# Random stop and probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, cantor-set

Suppose you have a particle moving on a staight line at speed $v_0$. The particle will stop when a totally random event happens (for example a radioactive nucleus decay). So the stop point will be a random point $x_0$. Because the Cantor - Dedekind axiom, the calculated probability to stop exatly in that point is $P(x_0)=0$ that means there is no possibility for the particle to stop there. Despite this, the particle will stop in $x_0$. Is this a paradox or there is a simple explanation I miss?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you hint, that each coin is one-sided then? You flip once and you get tails, does it mean that the coin have two tails?

Comment: An event can have probability $0$ but that does not mean that is *impossible* that it occurs. For any continuous rv $X$ we have $P(X=x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$. Nevertheless $X$ will take a specific value. That's the reason for terminology like "almost sure" instead of "sure".

Comment: I think you need to recall the definition of probability as a measure of event. So the measure assigned to outcomes "stop at $x_0$" is 0, though it could be many many outcomes, ended there. Just not enough for them to have a non-zero measure.